# Comma Separator to count

Tags: shell, unix, sparc

when I cat the csv file for head | wc -l 
it gives me answer as 1 
since there are comma in between , I wanted it to eliminate the comma and give me the count as 7

Eg :

```
cat file1.csv 
row1,row2,row3,row4,row5,row6,row7

cat file1.csv | head -1 | wc -l
1
```

But I wanted the answer to be 7 as it should give me counts of the rows

Answer (score 3):

You could replace the `,` with newline using `tr`:

```
tr , '\n' < file1.csv | wc -l
```

Or you could count the fields with awk:

```
awk -F, '{ print NF }' < file1.csv
```

Or you could delete everything but the commas with `sed` and then count the characters:

```
sed -e 's/[^,]//g' file1.csv | wc -c
```